# problem with skype installation

Tags: skype

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. While installing skype an error message is shown as **cannot install libqtgui4:i386**

I am using Linux for the first time.

Kindly help

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show us the exact command you entered and the complete output.

Comment: aggred with @GunnarHjalmarsson you should explain in question how did you install skype

Comment: ...also what other methods you have tried, and the output of `uname -mpi`. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/499878/edit) these into your question.

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, and retry the installation. Also, show us the command.